# $\int d^3x e^{ -i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|} = 4\pi \frac{1}{|\vec{k}|^2}$?

Tags: integration, quantum-field-theory

Reading the Schwartz quantum field theory p.235 I came across the following integration (Calculating Born approximation) :

$$ \frac{m_e^2}{4\pi^2}(\int d^{3}x e^{-i \vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}} \frac{e^2}{4\pi |\vec{x}|})^2=\frac{m_e^2}{4\pi^{2}}
(\frac{e^2}{|\vec{k}|^2})^2 $$

My question is, literally,
$$\int d^3x e^{ -i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|} = 4\pi \frac{1}{|\vec{k}|^2}$$ ?

If this is true, we maybe prove the above integration. And is it true? Can anyone help?

**My first attempt** : I will try to show that $$\int d^3k e^{ -i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}\frac{1}{|\vec{k}|} = 4\pi \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|^2}.$$ Then by changing  $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{x}$, we get the desired result.

By introducing Spherical coordinate and letting $r:=|\vec{x}|$, we have

$$\int d^3k e^{ -i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}\frac{1}{|\vec{k}|} 
  = \int^{\infty}_{0}d|\vec{k}| \int^{\pi}_{0} d\theta \int^{2\pi}_{0}d\phi \frac{1}{|\vec{k}|}e^{-i|\vec{k}||\vec{x}|cos\theta}|\vec{k}|^2 sin\theta$$

$$ = \int^{2\pi}_{0}d\phi \int^{\infty}_{0}d|\vec{k}|\int^{\pi}_{0}d\theta e^{-i|\vec{k}|rcos\theta}|\vec{k}|sin\theta  
   \overset{\mathrm{u=cos\theta}}{=} 2\pi \int^{\infty}_{0}|\vec{k}|d|\vec{k}| \int^{-1}_{1} -due^{-i|\vec{k}|ru}$$

$$= 2\pi \int^{\infty}_{0}|\vec{k}|d|\vec{k}|\int^{1}_{-1}du e^{-i|\vec{k}|r u} = 2\pi \int^{\infty}_{0}|\vec{k}|d|\vec{k}|[\frac{1}{-i|\vec{k}|r}e^{-i|\vec{k}|ru}]^{1}_{-1} $$
$$ = 2\pi \int^{\infty}_{0}|\vec{k}|d|\vec{k}| \frac{1}{-i|\vec{k}|r}(e^{-i|\vec{k}|r} - e^{i|\vec{k}|r}) = \frac{2\pi i}{r} \int^{\infty}_{0} d|\vec{k}|(e^{-i|\vec{k}|r} - e^{i |\vec{k}|r})$$

And note that

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} d|\vec{k}|e^{-i|\vec{k}|r} = \frac{1}{-ir}e^{-ir|\vec{k}|} |^{\infty}_{0} = \frac{1}{-ir}\cdot 0 - (\frac{1}{-ir}\cdot 1) = \frac{1}{ir} $$

and

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} d|\vec{k}|(-e^{i|\vec{k}|r}) = -\frac{1}{ir}e^{ir|\vec{k}|}|^{\infty}_{0} = -\infty + \frac{1}{ir} $$
.

So,

$$\frac{2\pi i}{r} \int^{\infty}_{0} d|\vec{k}|(e^{-i|\vec{k}|r} - e^{i |\vec{k}|r}) = \frac{2\pi i}{r} [\frac{1}{ir}-\infty+\frac{1}{ir}] = \frac{2\pi i}{r} [\frac{2}{ir} -\infty] =4\pi \frac{1}{r^2} -\infty = 4 \pi \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|^2}-\infty $$.

An issue that makes me annoying is the appearence of $\infty$. My calculation is correct? Where did I made mistake? Can any one point out?

Comment: Hint: if you introduce an extra $e^{-mr}$ factor in the integrand with $r:=|\vec{x}|$, the integral becomes $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi d\theta\sin\theta\int_0^\infty re^{-(m+ik\cos\theta)r}dr$ in polar coordinates. Substitute $u=-\cos\theta$, then take $m\to0^+$.

Comment: @J.G. O.K. Inspired by your hint, I made calculation of my own. But an unexpected infinity appeared :) Can you review my calculation?

Comment: That's why I suggested the $e^{-mr}$ factor, which obtains $4\pi/(m^2+k^2)$.

Comment: Aha, such a mechanism really works? Thank you. There have been such a profound reason. I'm a bit uneasy about whether or not the rigor is guaranteed in the technique of adding such a factor and taking the limit later. It seems like a bit of a trick.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential#Fourier_transform).

Comment: Thanks for link~

Comment: It is a trick that happens to work. What makes you think it isn't rigorous?

Comment: @Plantation  In fact, this trick is equivalent to computing the Laplace transform, such that $s = m + ik$ is the Laplace variable.

Comment: @Abexhiko : Oh really? I think that I am unfamiler to Laplace transform. Uhm I think I need to research and study more about the Laplace transform to understand. Thank you for pointing out.~